# Faceted on multiple values of the same field in haystack

Tags: solr, django-haystack

I am using Haystack and SOLR. And I am trying to implement faceting search on one field for multiple values. For example, I am faceting on "author" field.

```
john 3
kevin 2
sam 2
```

I want to faceted on "john" OR "sam". How can I format the URL for it?

```
http://localhost:8000/search/?q=*&selected_facets=author_exact:john +OR+ selected_facets=author_exact:sam
```

Comment: So do you only want the values for `john` and `sam` in your facets, or do you want to limit the resultset to only include documents with `john` or `sam` in the field?

Comment: @MatsLindh I am doing faceting on "author" field. I want to the results for value "john" or "sam".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the resulting set of documents to those containing either `john` or `sam`, use a `fq`:

```
fq=author:sam OR author:john
```

If you want to only generate facets on certain values or queries, use [`facet.query`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.query_%3a_Arbitrary_Query_Faceting):

```
facet.query=author:sam OR author:john
```

Comment: This is SOLR query syntax, but how can I format it to Haystack URL request?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Haystack, sorry. But [from the documentation, it seems that .filter is the way to go](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html).

Comment: Anyway, Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use OR with narrow() in your view/form (the exact implementation depends on which view/form you are using).

Since getting the list of selected_facets simply involves:
  self.request.GET.getlist('selected_facets')

How you wish to implement that in your url is solely up to you:

- you could do it with some kind of separator then you split them apart:
  **localhost:8000/search/?q=*&selected_facets=author_exact:john|sam**

  `for x in selected_facets:
  field_name, value = x.split(':', 1)

  if "|" not in value:
     continue
  values = x.split('|')`
- you could also do it this way:
  **localhost:8000/search/q=*&selected_facets=author_exact:john&selected_facets=author_exact:sam**

  facet_dict = dict()
  for x in selected_facets:
    field_name, value = x.split(':', 1)
    facet_dict[field_name].append(value)

**Then in haystack:**
  *sqs.narrow('author_exact:(john OR sam)')*

So basically there are no strict rules/standards for how to implement multiple values in the url for faceting.